# Credential Dialog, disabling default Realm information messages disclosing password

Tags: qgis, postgis, security

I'm using the QgsCredentialDialog for determining user access to the database. When a user is failing to log in correctly the log in credentials are shown in the dialog (Fig. 1).

```
(success, uname, passwd) = \
 QgsCredentialDialog.instance().get(connInfo, None, None, "Log in")
```

Despite the credentials being faulty there's the case where username is misspelled but the password is correct.
As a minimum, I'd like it if the entered password was not shown in the "Realm" message at the top of the dialog.

Is it possible, via Python, to disable this messages in the dialog or am I better off creating my own credentials dialog in Qt?

[image: Failing log in]

Comment: Could you open a [bug report](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index#bugs-features-and-issues.html) for this? I think this is a serious security issue and you are probably not the only one affected. Fixing this upstream should be preferred to implementing a local workaround.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Certainly. [Bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10134)